# Trouble calling syscall by name

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am in process of adding system calls to linux Kernel 3.19. Tried out the following for adding a syscall 'add' for x86 arch in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. 
src=3.19 source

1. Added entry to src/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl.

   ```
   323 common add sys_add
   ```
2. Added syscall prototype to src/include/syscalls.h.

   ```
   asmlinakge sys_add(int i,int j);
   ```
3. Wrote **add.c** in **fs** directory, added **add.o** in **fs/Makefile** .
4. In file **src/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h**

Added lines

```
    #define __NR_add 323

  __SYSCALL(__NR_add, sys_add);
```

5. Compiled and built the kernel. It was success. The output of **uname -r** gives 3.19.
6. Created a program to test new syscall.

   6.1 Used the function **syscall(323,10,15)**. It was success as the sum of values(25) was printed.

   6.2 When trying to call syscall by name, it gives

   ```
     /tmp/ccpxRp8C.o: In function `main':
      testadd1.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `add'
      collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```

What am I missing??

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the little piece of assembly code that, when assembled, shows up as a C-linkable symbol.

If you do this:

```
ar t /usr/lib/libc.a | grep write.o
```

you will see that the (statically-linkable) C library has a small file named "write.o". This contains a little piece of assembled code that defines a symbol `__libc_write` that's visible outside of `write.o`. That little piece of assembled code puts the value 1 in a specific register, which is the number that Linux and Unix kernels know as the "write" system call, sets up other registers very carefully, then executes a `syscall` instruction (on my x86_64 machine).

You will have to create just such a piece of assembly code for your "add" system call. Or, you can you the `syscall` system call, just as you have been doing, writing a plain C function to make it look lke you've got an `add()` system call.

You don't say what architecture (x86 or x86_64) you're using, but here's an x86_64 implementation of `write(2)`.  It does set `errno` correctly, and it returns the number of bytes written, but the argument types aren't correct.

```
int
linux_write(int fd, const void *data, unsigned long len)
{

    long ret;
    asm volatile ("syscall" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (__NR_write),
              "D" (fd), "S" (data), "d" (len) :
              "cc", "memory", "rcx",
              "r8", "r9", "r10", "r11" );
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        errno = -ret;
        ret = -1;
    }
    return (int)ret;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The above code is to be done in kernel itself? Also, whats the use of  **step 4**?

Comment: @AsishKSahadevan - no it resides in a separate file, and gets compiled by itself. At that point you've got an object file (.o file) that can be linked with your C program that's missing a symbol. The object file provides the symbol, and code that does a `syscall` which gets your program into the kernel.  Step 4 is so you can use the `syscall()` generic system call execution function. You don't need to do step 4 if you're writing your own assembly stub.